# How to do a JSON api call with error response?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I use Javascript to retrieve through a JSON api call the amount of active products pasted in a certain filter.
My typicall response would be

```json
{"total":34,"product_ids":["PRODUCT1","PRODUCT2",....."]}
```

My script is working fine when products are present but when none of the products are active the response will be:

```json
{"error":"No products found, please check request settings"}
```

In this case the script will crash.

What I tried to do is to set the var `NumEdPicks` to `0` when I get an error but I don't really know how as the script is crashing when it doesn't find "total".

This is what the retrieve part of the script looks like

```js
// Retrieve
var url = 'http://api.jetlore.com/products/products_by_filter.json?jl_cid=' + clientID + '&filter=' + filterName + '&per_page=' + maxCount + '&page=1';
var response = HTTP.Get(url);
var responseObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response["Content"]);
var NumEditorsPick = responseObj.total;
if(NumEditorsPick>maxCount){ var NumEditorsPick = maxCount;}
```

I would like to set `NumEditorsPick` to 0 when I get the error response.
Some things I was thinking about but which isn't working:

```js
var NumEditorsPick = responseObj.total || 0
```

or

```js
var NumEditorsPick = ‘total’ in responseObj ? responseObj.total : 0
```

How to define `NumEditorsPick` when there is no total?

I've tried so far:

```
if (responseObj.hasOwnProperty('total')){
  var NumEditorsPick = responseObj.total;
}else{
  var NumEditorsPick = 0;
}
```

And

```
  if (responseObj.has("total")){var NumEditorsPick = responseObj.total;
}
  if (responseObj.has("error")){var NumEditorsPick = 0;
}
```

Both are crashing the execution of my script, so I'm starting to think that when there is an error response it just stops the script and ignores the rest, would that be possible? In that case, how to ignore this error response?

EDIT:
After using the try/catch method as suggested in the comments, I managed to finally make it work:

```
var NumEditorsPick;

  try {
    var response = HTTP.Get(url);
    var responseObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response["Content"]);
    NumEditorsPick = responseObj.total;
  } catch (error) {
    NumEditorsPick = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript's [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the parse JSON has the key you're looking for.

In this case, I'd be something like:

```
var responseObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response["Content"]);
if (responseObj.hasOwnProperty('error')){
    // handle error msg
}else{
    // do something else
}
```

[Here's a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/Graz21/xzk0h8Lu/3/) using the JSON input you've provided.

---

## Update

Ok, so my initial answer was based on what you said here:

> My script is working fine when products are present but when none of
>   the products are active the response will be:
>
> `{"error":"No products found, please check request settings"}`

But the service you're calling does not return a JSON string containing the error. Instead it returns a 404 and therefore, any attempt to parse or use the response content is not valid.

So, to start, you could try wrapping your `HTTP.Get(url)`in a try/catch method and on the catch clause set the `NumEdPicks` to zero.

Another option would be to check `HTTP.Get()` method documentation to see if the response object has a status (e.g: `response.Status`) or if you can pass a callback function for response and error, like this example in AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourUrl',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){ 
        // Set NumEdPicks to total and do other stuff 
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // Set NumEdPicks to zero
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.
I've tried a couple of variations of your idea and unfortunately it is still crashing when 0 products are active (when >0, it runs perfectly fine).

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried after reading my answer

Comment: I've update my answer with a working example, hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hey Grazina, thank you so much for helping me out here, I've updated my question to show what I've tried so far. It still crashes only in the case of the error message.

Comment: What error are you getting and where? You should declare `NumEditorsPick` outside the scope of the **if** to use it later

Comment: Regrettably the only error I'm getting when running the script in our automation studio is: `ERROR:  Error has occurred`. I've declared the `NumEditorsPick` before and still getting an error...

Comment: Can you log `response["Content"]` and  `responseObj` after you call the parse function?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how I can log these objects as I'm running the script inside an automation. I've tried `console.log(response["Content"]);` but this is not pulling through in the error log. Any ideas how I could log these objects and see what's going on?

Comment: Well you can try to put the URL in your browser (with the variable's values) and check what JSON it renders, assuming it only needs the `ClientID`for authorisation.  Another idea would be to use [Javascript's try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Extratos_e_declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es/try...catch) and on the catch function set `NumEditorsPick = 0`

Comment: I managed to run the script elsewhere and log the `response["Content"]` and `reponseObj`. I'm getting this:
`{"total":626,"product_ids":["100734","100900","101309","101300","100979","101086","100964","101175","101043","101047"]} System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]`
Only when there are deals present. When it doesn't find any deals I'm getting:
`An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call. URL: [...]
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`
It recognizes the error response and stops the script...

Comment: It worked with the try/catch method! Thank you so much for this, it was really bugging me and this will help improving our processes a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)